# How to import python module from a different directory into jupyter notebook

Tags: python, module, package

I have a project which is structured as below:

```
/project
    /src
        __init__.py
        my_module.py
    /notebooks
        my_notebook.ipynb
```

I wanted to import `my_module.py` in `my_notebook.ipynb`, so I first tried `import src.my_module` getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'` and `from ..src import my_module` getting `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. From several similar topics I found that adding `/project` location to SYSPATH would be a quick hack and it works indeed:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/project')
from src import my_module
```

However, interfering with SYSPATH seems to be a nasty way and I wonder - does a safer/cleaner solution exists. Also, I don't quite get why `from ..src import my_module` doesn't work in the first place?

Comment: Try adding an __init__ file to the main folder then try `from .src.my_module import translate`

Comment: It didn't help...

Comment: I think you can solve your doubts here [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)